# How does ‘Pocket Dimension’ work?

Tags: spells, chronicles-of-darkness-2e, mage-the-awakening-2e

Specifically, when cast without adding Time 2 (so time would flow normally), it seems intuitively that anything in the pocket dimension would effectively be frozen in place, making it the equivalent of spell Temporal Stutter (time 4).

Except that you have to do three spells, one to make the pocket, one to teleport the target to the pocket dimension and another to teleport them back.

But this intuition seems wrong based on how the spell is actually described.

Can you sleep, walk around, cast spells and/or study in the pocket dimension? (It says someone can walk around forever in any direction...)

I am assuming you can't heal naturally, and this also means you don't bleed out. I would take it to also mean you don't need to breath air (as it explicitly mentions needing air if you add the normal flow of time).

Thinking about it a bit more, it seems that the Time 2 "Time flows normally within the pocket dimension" is a ruling effect - so by adding it you are not creating time from nothing (that being a making practice requiring Time 5) - thus there must be time (somewhere) to start with... Not sure still if that somewhere is in the pocket dimension or in the timestream where the mage is casting from...

Comment: Extension, how do you target this spell (eg for veiling, sheilding or any other practice). I am thinking specifically of Supernal Dispellation, Wards and Signs, and Supernal Veil - to dispel, Ward, and veil the spell, respectively. And should this be a seperate question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've come to a conclusion: without time there is only space in the pocket dimension. So anything entering it is held in stasis (as per the intuitive answer above).

This does indeed replicate some of the effect of temporal Stutter (Time 4) with Pocket Dimension (Space 5) and lower space effects (teleportation).

The difference is Temporal Stutter is withstood by the target's Stamina, while Teleporting someone into a Pocket Dimension is withstood by the sympathetic link (the mage who cast the pocket counts for a material sympathetic yantra, but how strong the connection is not clear in the RAW).

I am inclined to say the Pocket Dimension has a strong sympathetic link to the mage who created it. Which makes it very easy to teleport people into (at least people you are touching or within sensory range of).

The spells seems to be usable as a 'bag of holding', but with enough volume (taken as scale dice penalties) could he used as a very effective prison.

- in responce to the extension. Inside the Pocket Dimension anyone can target the spell with mage sight, or supernal vision. Otherwise you need to find a spatial sympathy leading into the space and scry and use remote viewing with mage sight to acquire the target and a dispellation (Aside: sympathy to a person trapped inside and Teleporting them out is easier).